# Pass a value to an action in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an action that redirect to another action:

```
public ActionResult Create(Score score)
{
     score.DateOfSubmit = DateTime.Now.Date;
     obj.AddNewScore(score);
     obj.Save();
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Score");
}
```

I want to pass an id to **index** action in last line .so how can pass an **id** to index action .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Score", new { id = score.Id });
```

Answer (score 2):

Do like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(Score score)
{
    score.DateOfSubmit = DateTime.Now.Date;
    obj.AddNewScore(score);
    obj.Save();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Score", new {id=score.Id});
}
```

and in `Index` action do like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    return View();
}
```